# Как использовать массив $arParams в прикрепленном файле.js ?

Tags: битрикс, javascript

Имеется уже готовый написанный `js` файл, в котором указываются начальные параметры выводимого компонента (на данный момент они статичные, т.е.: `var selectedCountryId = 6`, как сделать чтобы эти данные брались из параметров компонента? в js новичок, так что не ругайтесь..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно предусмотреть что бы данные были заполены до подключения этого js файла.
Как пример:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = {
    a: 'Hello',
    b: 'world',
    c: <?= $ar['username'] ?>
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mycode.js"></script>
```

Ещё можно аяксом ходить на сервак и получать данные, а скрипт вставлять уже в выполнении каллбека.

Comment: в компоненте:
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = {
 a: <?= $arParams['VIDEOCOUNTRY_DEFAULT_COLS'] ?>,
 b: <?= $arParams['VIDEOCOUNTRY_DEFAULT_COUNT'] ?>,
 c: <?= $arParams['VIDEOCOUNTRY_DEFAULT_COUNTRY'] ?>
};
</script>
<script src="/bitrix/js/bronni/pages/video.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

в самом video.js следующее:
var v_columns = data.a;
var v_random = data.b;
var selectedCountryId = data.c; 

но все равно не работает.. ((((

Comment: по всей видимости ошибка в обращении к php переменной, поскольку при вставке обычных значений, имхо: 
<script type="text/javascript">
 var data = {
  a: 2,
  b: 3,
  c: 6
  };
</script>
все работает, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Проблема решена, спасибо)